# Binding DataTable to a DataGrid - first two columns empty no matter what

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid, datatable

I'm binding a DataTable to a DataGrid, however, the first two columns are always empty, although it clearly has content.

For example, the **DataTable** contains following:

```
╔═════════╦═════════╦═════════╦═════════╗
║ Columm1 ║ Column2 ║ Column3 ║ Column4 ║
╠═════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════════╣
║ A1      ║ A2      ║ A3      ║ A4      ║
║ B1      ║ B2      ║ B3      ║ A4      ║
║ C1      ║ C2      ║ C3      ║ C4      ║
╚═════════╩═════════╩═════════╩═════════╝
```

The content can be confirmed by looping through the rows, which displays the correct output:

```
foreach (DataRow r in Test.Rows)
{
    MessageBox.Show(r[0] + ", " + r[1] + ", " + r[2] + ", " +  r[3]);
}
```

But when, I finally bind the DataTable to the DataGrid...

```
datagrid.DataContext = Test.DefaultView;
```

The first two columns of the **DataGrid** *go missing*:

```
╔═════════╦═════════╦═════════╦═════════╗
║ Columm1 ║ Column2 ║ Column3 ║ Column4 ║
╠═════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════════╣
║         ║         ║ A3      ║ A4      ║
║         ║         ║ B3      ║ A4      ║
║         ║         ║ C3      ║ C4      ║
╚═════════╩═════════╩═════════╩═════════╝
```

I have no clue why. The DataGrid seems to be configured correctly.

```xml
<DataGrid x:Name="datagrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="810,142,0,0"
          VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="495" Width="400" IsReadOnly="True"
          ItemsSource="{Binding}" BorderThickness="0,1,1,1"/>
```

---

### Problem

The column names contained punctuation. Removing those solved the issue.

Comment: I briefly looked at one of my wpf datagrids and I used the ItemsSource property instead of DataContext.  You might try that:

datagrid.ItemsSource = Test.DefaultView;

Comment: +1 just for formatting your tables with those ASCII characters!

Comment: @ZoAnimus Hm, the issue's still there.

Comment: Try to create a minimal problem reproducing example, so people can get the full picture. You probably will figure out the source of the problem in the process.

Comment: Do you column names contain any special characters or weird punctuation?   That was the problem from this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897833/unable-to-display-data-in-a-wpf-datagrid-that-has-a-dataview-instance-as-the-item/2898572#comment-7327085

Comment: @ZoAnimus Oh my god, you found the problem. My column names had some periods in it. Now it's working fine. Thanks!

Comment: Great!  I'll post a simple answer for future reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wpf Datagrids have issues if there are special characters or punctuation in the column names.   If you remove those characters, it should function as expected.