# What column names are allowed when binding a C# DataTable to a WPF DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I am writing some UI which takes a C# `DataTable` from another library, and attempts to display it in a WPF `DataGrid`. This causes binding errors (and to the user, row display errors or missing data) when the columns within the `DataTable` have special characters (ex `.` or `[]`). I could perhaps try to replace the special characters out, so hence my question:

Is there a reference as to what is legal for a column name, vs. what might cause a binding error?

In this simple code, I have created a WPF form with a `DataGrid`, and bound it to a `DataTable`:

```
public DataTable Table { get; private set; }

public MainWindow()
{
    // Set up a table
    Table = new DataTable();
    Table.Columns.Add("a");
    Table.Columns.Add("a.1");
    Table.Columns.Add("a[]");
    Table.Rows.Add("1", "2.", "3.");
    InitializeComponent();

    DataContext = this;
}
```

The code above produces the following binding errors:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : 
BindingExpression path error: '[]' property not found on 'object' ''String' (HashCode=-842352753)'. BindingExpression:Path=a[]; DataItem='DataRowView' (HashCode=44777048); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 :
BindingExpression path error: '1' property not found on 'object' ''String' (HashCode=-842352753)'. BindingExpression:Path=a.1; DataItem='DataRowView' (HashCode=14413736); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
```

Thanks!

Comment: I spent a bit of time researching this to see if I could find anything related- the closest I found was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24679884/binding-datatable-to-a-datagrid-first-two-columns-empty-no-matter-what) where @ZoAnimus said _"wpf Datagrids have issues if there are special characters or punctuation in the column names. If you remove those characters, it should function as expected. "_.

Comment: Given the nature of the problem, it seems clear that the issue is WPF is interpreting these names using its normal string path parsing logic. So the reference you are actually looking for is the WPF binding path documentation. Any "special characters" that would be interpreted by the parser need to be avoided.

Comment: Agreed, @Peter, thanks- unfortunately I have not been able to find that documentation. Do you have any pointers? Thanks!

Comment: There's an overview of the syntax at [Binding Declarations Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752300(v=vs.110).aspx) and a more detailed discussion at [PropertyPath XAML Syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742451(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Great, thanks @Peter!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some reflection during the binding and finding the propery, which means that you cannot specify a column name which would cause a "syntax error" during the reflection.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613546(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful!, but unfortunately the link didn't give me a clear picture of what classes of characters would cause that syntax error. Playing around has shown . and [] to be difficult; but is there better documentation that shows exactly what syntax is allowed?

Comment: You can check the language spec about property names: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=7029 , chapter 2.4.2

Comment: Thanks @Dexion- this in combination with Peter's answers earlier give me a clear picture.